# Azure AD Graph API - How you can get the IssuerAssignedId for Google and Facebook

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm following the Microsoft tutorial [Create a user (local or social account)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#CreateLocalAccountUser). So I'm trying to create a user from HTTP call, for this I'm sending a similar payload to the tutorial:

```
{
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "creationType": "LocalAccount",
  "displayName": "Alex Wu",
  "passwordProfile": {
    "password": "Test1234",
    "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": false
  },
  "signInNames": [
    {
      "type": "userName",
      "value": "AlexW"
    },
    {
      "type": "emailAddress",
      "value": "alexw@gmail.com"
    }
  ],
  "userIdentities": [
    {
      "issuer": "google.com",
      "issuerUserId": "MATxTNg5MzYyMzMyMNY1Njc="
    }
  ]
}
```

My question is how I can generate the `issuerUserId` as it is necessary for the Google supplier to recognize the user. I'm trying with a random value encode with base64 but when I run the user flow the user it's created again with a duplicate email. I suppose Google don't recognize the `issuerUserId`.

**Update:**

Base on Allen Wu answer:

> issuerUserId is a unique user identifier for the issuer. You can set any valid string (don't be duplicate) for it.

I create this `issuerUserId` with a valid string: `12345678909823456789`

As before, I create successfully the user and the source show as `Google`:

[image]

But when I want to log in the account with Google provider

[image]

The user is duplicated:

[image]

I assume instead of launch Sign in process Azure/Google don't recognize the account's `issuerUserId` and launch the Sign-up process, for that reason that's why I think `issuerUserId` might be created by Google.

**Some notes:**

- I'm changed the emails for demo emails, but that is the current
  behavior.
- I'm only using Google authentication, I don't using email and password fields of the login, because the purpose of the app is only for Social Authentication (Google specifically)
- I'm using `Sign up and sign in (Recommended)` user type flow.
- If you have more thoughts about `issuerUserId` that can help me, let me know, I'll really appreciate.

Comment: Hi did you have a chance to look into my answer? Any updates?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I added an update.

Comment: Do you mean that when you use the credential of the google account created via AAD Graph to sign in (not sign up) with Google provider in user flow, it creates a new duplicated user for you?

Comment: Yes, exactly that

Comment: Have updated my answer. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true.

Based on my test, the user flow won't create a new user which has a duplicate email. (the previous user is created via AAD Graph)

[image]

`issuerUserId` is a unique user identifier for the issuer. You can set any valid string (don't be duplicate) for it.

And Google / Facebook or any other social idp won't verify it, because this user is created in B2C. It's an B2C local account. (`"creationType": "LocalAccount"`)

Create an B2C local account doesn't mean this user has been created in Google.

I guess that you add Google idp into the user flow and are trying to create a new user in Google rather than B2C.

You should click on the "Sign up now" in user flow to create the local account. Kindly check it.

[image]

---

**Update:**

As I have mentioned above, the user you created with Azure AD graph is an B2C local account. You should use the default sign in feature to log into that user. B2C will verify your credential.

[image]

But when you click on the "Google" to sign in, in fact the Google will verify your credential and will associate your Google account to a new B2C account. It's not a local account.

So they are two different accounts. You can verify this by changing the password of the B2C local account. After changing the password, you still need to use the old password to sign in with the "Google" option. But you will need to use the new password to sign in with the first user (B2C local account).

You can use `GET https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users?api-version` to get the two users and find that the `issuerUserId` of them are different.

Comment: Ok I understand, so I can't create a Google user programmatically with the AD Graph API, correct, and I always necessarily have to use the default sign in feature with local accounts.

Comment: @israteneda Yes. You are correct. If my answer is helpful, you can mark it as accepted. Thank you:)